# Calling Python Function in Robot Framework Test Cases

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a function need to call in Robot framework test cases. I using Library features but the keywords still undectable. Why ah?

```
Library  ../API/Oppenheimer.py


`*** Test Cases ***
Test title "Create Hero"
    createWorkingClassHero()`



`def createWorkingClassHero():
    db.connectDB()
    db.insertDB()`

    return "DB Data Object was created"





I tried with library and modules but still undectable.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *** Settings ***
 Library  ../API/Oppenheimer.py

*** Test Cases ***
TestTitleCreateHero
    ${status}    createWorkingClassHero
    Log    ${status}
```

Try using this way